# OAuth authentication failed on PUT

Tags: django, http, oauth, put

I am using **OAuth** within my project. but I have come into an authentication problem.

It is that I can pass the authentification mechanism of Oauth with the method "POST" but not the method "PUT". The only difference between the POST and PUT request is the method type. The body and the header is the same. The requests I used are as follows :

**POST**

```
resp, cont = client.request("http://localhost:8000/api/1.0/booking/",
                            "POST", 
                            data_booking,
                            headers=headers)
```

**PUT**

```
resp, cont = client.request("http://localhost:8000/api/1.0/booking/",
                            "PUT",
                            data_booking,
                            headers=headers)
```

The client is a OAuth client.

The error message returned by server is :

[image]

Fyi : 401 Unauthorized

Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is possible but has failed or not yet been provided

I am developing using the django framework.

The request method is as follow :

```
def request(self, uri, method="GET", body=None, headers=None, 
        redirections=httplib2.DEFAULT_MAX_REDIRECTS, connection_type=None,
        callback_url=None, realm=''):
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        if not isinstance(headers, dict):
            headers = {}

        is_multipart = method == 'POST' and headers.get('Content-Type', 
            DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE) != DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE

        if body and (method == "POST" or method == 'PUT') and not is_multipart:
            parameters = dict(parse_qsl(body))
            if callback_url != None:
                parameters['oauth_callback'] = callback_url
        else:
            if callback_url != None and not is_multipart:
                parameters = {'oauth_callback': callback_url}
            else:
                parameters = None

        req = Request.from_consumer_and_token(self.consumer, 
            token=self.token, http_method=method, http_url=uri, 
            parameters=parameters)

        req.sign_request(self.method, self.consumer, self.token)

        if method == "POST" or method == "PUT":
            headers['Content-Type'] = headers.get('Content-Type', 
                DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE)
            if is_multipart:
                headers.update(req.to_header(realm))
            else:
                body = req.to_postdata()
        elif method == "GET":
            uri = req.to_url()
        else:
            headers.update(req.to_header(realm))

        return httplib2.Http.request(self, uri, method=method, body=body, 
            headers=headers, redirections=redirections, 
            connection_type=connection_type)
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: are you getting any errors? I dont think there is enough information in the question to be able to help you.

Comment: @diagonalbatman I have added the answer I received from the server side.

Comment: Are you returning a specific error? I think we need to see more of your code.

Comment: @diagonalbatman I have pasted the code for the request method. Is this enough? Or it needs more to understand my problem? thx

Answer (score 1):

Some OAuth server implementations only include form-encoded body parameters in the signature base string when the HTTP method is POST. This was the right behavior in OAuth 1.0 but was corrected in later revisions. Try making a PUT request without a body and see if that helps. If it does, you will need to ask the server library maintainer to fix this or limit your calls not to include a form-encoded body when using a put.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I have created a oauth client using python. It seems that the client.request will only populate the oauth parameters when the method is "post". For "put", I did this manually, and it works. Strange! Btw, thanks for you tuto on oauth.